# UITableview moves cell to wrong section and replaces its previous location with a blank one

Tags: swift

I have a UITableview that dynamically adds tableviewcells to the tableview once it has detected something in the cells textview that comes before it. To make the uitableviewcell that the user is typing in center I move the insets with Notifications.

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillShow(_:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillHide(_:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)

@objc func keyboardWillShow(_ notification : Notification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
        creationTableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0.0, left: 0.0, bottom: keyboardSize.height, right: 0.0)
        //creationTableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = creationTableView.contentInset
    }
}

@objc func keyboardWillHide(_ notification : Notification) {
    creationTableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0.0, left: 0.0, bottom: 0.0, right: 0.0)
    //creationTableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = creationTableView.contentInset
}
```

The problem here is when I move the uitableview insets too far to the point where the topmost cell moves down to the section despite my code not allowing that to happen. An example of what happens in the video is when the cell that says "Butter" moves down into where im typing near the end of the video.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKsxa.jpg)

The problem that I need solved is how do I stop this from ocurring?

Edit: Added code for the creation of the cells and the actual tableviewcell class itself.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = creationTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "recipeInstructionsCell", for: indexPath) as! RecipeInstructionsCell
    cell.selectionStyle = .none
    cell.indexPath = indexPath
    cell.tableViewMaster = self.creationTableView
    //cell.cellTextView.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.delegate = self


    if indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row < temporaryRecipeItem.ingredients.count && !temporaryRecipeItem.ingredients.isEmpty {
        cell.cellTextView.text = temporaryRecipeItem.ingredients[indexPath.row]
    } else if indexPath.row < temporaryRecipeItem.instructions.count && !temporaryRecipeItem.instructions.isEmpty {
        cell.cellTextView.text = temporaryRecipeItem.instructions[indexPath.row]
    }

    return cell
}


//Delegate Method
func editText(at indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = creationTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! RecipeInstructionsCell

    //if the cell has more than one character in it
    if cell.cellTextView.text.count == 1 {
        if creationTableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: indexPath.row + 1, section: indexPath.section)) == nil {
            self.addRow(at: indexPath)
        }
    } else {
        let oneAheadIndexPath = IndexPath(row: indexPath.row + 1, section: indexPath.section)
        let cellBelowCurrentCell = creationTableView.cellForRow(at: oneAheadIndexPath) as! RecipeInstructionsCell
        //If the current cell the user is typing in has all of its characters removed and a cell is empty below the user delete the cell below
        if cell.cellTextView.text.isEmpty && cellBelowCurrentCell.cellTextView.text.isEmpty {
            //cell.hasAddedRow = false
            self.deleteRow(at: indexPath)
        }
    }
    //creationTableView.scrollToRow(at: cell.indexPath!, at: .top, animated: false)
}

//If instructions contain keywords like cook, caramalize, fry ,whisk ,frying pan, dice, cut, grill, roast ,and temperatures display an appropriate image to go allow with the instruction in the

func addRow(at indexPath : IndexPath) {
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        numberOfIngredients += 1
    } else {
        numberOfInstructions += 1
    }
    print("Insert at section: \(indexPath.section) row: \(indexPath.row)")

    //Insert another cell ahead of the one the user is currently typing in
    let oneAheadIndexPath = IndexPath(row: indexPath.row + 1, section: indexPath.section)
    creationTableView.beginUpdates()
    creationTableView.insertRows(at: [oneAheadIndexPath], with: .right)
    creationTableView.endUpdates()
}

func deleteRow(at indexPath : IndexPath) {
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        numberOfIngredients -= 1
    } else {
        numberOfInstructions -= 1
    }
    //Delete another cell ahead of the one the user is currently in
    let oneAheadIndexPath = IndexPath(row: indexPath.row + 1, section: indexPath.section)
    creationTableView.beginUpdates()
    creationTableView.deleteRows(at: [oneAheadIndexPath], with: .right)
    creationTableView.endUpdates()
}
```

TableViewCellClass

```
protocol RecipeInstructionsCellProtocol {
    func editText(at indexPath : IndexPath)
}
```

class RecipeInstructionsCell: UITableViewCell, UITextViewDelegate {

```
@IBOutlet var cellTextView: UITextView!
var indexPath : IndexPath?
var tableViewMaster : UITableView?
var delegate : RecipeInstructionsCellProtocol?


override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    self.cellTextView.delegate = self
    self.cellTextView.tintColor = UIColor.blue
    self.cellTextView.autocorrectionType = .yes
    self.cellTextView.autocapitalizationType = .sentences
    //self.cellTextView.textColor = UIColor.lightGray
    self.cellTextView.isScrollEnabled = false
    self.cellTextView.textContainer.heightTracksTextView = true
    self.cellTextView.returnKeyType = .next
}



func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
    let size = textView.bounds.size
    let newSize = textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: size.width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))

    if size.height != newSize.height {
        self.tableViewMaster?.beginUpdates()
        self.tableViewMaster?.endUpdates()

        //let thisIndexPath = IndexPath(row: textView.tag, section: 0)
    }
    delegate?.editText(at: (self.indexPath!))
}

func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    if text == "\n" {
        if tableViewMaster!.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: self.indexPath!.row + 1, section: self.indexPath!.section)) != nil {
            self.cellTextView.resignFirstResponder()
            let cell = tableViewMaster?.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: self.indexPath!.row + 1, section: self.indexPath!.section)) as! RecipeInstructionsCell
            cell.cellTextView.becomeFirstResponder()
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

}

Comment: Please show all relevant code for inserting your rows.

Comment: When you are creating a new cell are you storing what the value typed in by user in a variable or view controller? I think the problem here is, you have left the text typed by the user "Butter" in this case, in the UI and when that cell gets dequeued, the cell retains the valued you had typed earlier. If you can show us the code where you create the cells it would be helpful.

Comment: That’s why I wanted to see the code for cellforrowatindexpath

Comment: Added the code for inserting the rows.

Comment: Try cell.cellTextview.text =  ““ before the if Statement in cellforrowatindexpath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
let cell = creationTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "recipeInstructionsCell", for: indexPath) as! RecipeInstructionsCell
cell.selectionStyle = .none
cell.indexPath = indexPath
cell.tableViewMaster = self.creationTableView
//cell.cellTextView.tag = indexPath.row
cell.delegate = self
```

cell.cellTextView.text = ““

```
if indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row < temporaryRecipeItem.ingredients.count && !temporaryRecipeItem.ingredients.isEmpty {
    cell.cellTextView.text = temporaryRecipeItem.ingredients[indexPath.row]
} else if indexPath.row < temporaryRecipeItem.instructions.count && !temporaryRecipeItem.instructions.isEmpty {
    cell.cellTextView.text = temporaryRecipeItem.instructions[indexPath.row]
}

return cell
```

}

Comment: (https://imgur.com/a/UwfIZPk)
Your initial code worked and the cell wasnt inserted below where I was typing, now I think all I need to do is save the code in the cells into a list for the tableview to load from.

Comment: Please do not post code-only answers. A proper answer explains what was wrong and how the answer solves the issue. And please take time to properly format the code in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The underlying cause of the problem is that we have stored `state` in your tableview. According the Model-View-Controller pattern we should not should not store data in the view.

In this case, let us say your tableview fills the screen and has 10 rows, when the user scrolls down, when the top rows go off the screen, the table view will 'recycle' the rows and present them again at the bottom of the screen. This recycling of rows happens when you dequeue cells.

This is an optimisation that tableview has to prevent creating many rows when the user scroll really fast.

To solve this problem, when you the user enters a value in a textfield. As soon as the user has finished editing that row, you need to save the data entered in your data model. To do this, you can implement the `textViewDidEndEditing(_:)` delegate method to store the data for a cell in some data structure (an array in the view controller)

In the `cellForRowAt` method, each time you dequeue a cell, you should reset it to a default state. (clear out all the fields etc).

When the table reloads a cell for which the user already had entered data. Use the model and populated the cell.